# There a random 'b' that shouldn't be there

Tags: python, udp

So I am playing around with UDP communication in python and I finally got a little messaging thing to work but on the client side, there is a random 'b' 
here is my code

udpServer.py:

```
import socket
import time
import os
import getpass

userNonByt = getpass.getuser()
username = bytes(userNonByt, 'utf-8')
HOST = "localhost"
PORT =  5454
HOST = bytes(HOST, 'utf-8')
bytes(PORT)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

def setmsg():
    os.system('cls')
    #asks user for there text to send
    data = input("Send: ")
    #converts there text to bytes so it can be sent in the UDP Packet
    text = bytes(data, 'utf-8')
    #sends the users text
    s.sendto(username,(HOST,PORT))
    s.sendto((text),(HOST,PORT))
    #brings you back to the begining of this function
    setmsg()


setmsg()
```

udpClient.py:

```
import socket


HOST = 'localhost'
PORT =  5454
HOST = bytes(HOST, 'utf-8')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind((HOST,PORT))

while 1:
    print (s.recv(30))
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: switch to Python 2.7 and the `b` (in `b"..."`) will go away ;-)

Comment: `b"..."` just means it is a `bytestring` as opposed to a `unicode string` ...

Comment: Recursion is no replacement for loops.

Comment: The description of a 'random b' is particularly uninformative.  Good thing we are good at guessing, or we'd have closed this post hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are printing is encoded. Use .decode() to print the actual string.

```
while 1:
    print(s.recv(30).decode())
```